# ¿Cómo eliminar el primer espacio de la Regex?

Tags: javascript

Este regex valida números:

```js
var patron = /[0-9\s]/ig;
var b = "    49";
console.log(b.match(patron).join(""));
```

Pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que elimine los espacios del principio? Solamente con la expresión regular ?

Answer (score 2):

Con tu regex estás obteniendo también los espacios.

Una sencilla solución es comprobar si hay un número en el string, pero sin los espacios:

```js
var patron = /\d+/;
var b = "    49";
console.log(b.match(patron)[0]);
```

Otra solución, más sencilla, es utilizar `trim`, que elimina los espacios al principio y final de una cadena de texto:

```js
var b = "    49";
console.log(b.trim());
```